# Custom Wordpress Docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

I need to build a wordpress container(preferably using dockerfile) which has the following;

1. Self signed SSL certificate for Apache
2. Custom wp-config.php

How do I do that through a dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not into `WordPress` but it should look something like this.

I have taken the defaults from the [official docker hub repo](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/).

[image]

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

ADD my.crt /etc/ssl/certs/my.crt
ADD my.key /etc/ssl/private/my.key

ADD wp-config.php /path/to/your/config/wp-config.php
```

*Make sure that the certs are located at the right position for your `apache`/`wordpress` config.*

`stack.yml`:

```
version: '2.0'

services:

  wordpress:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Run with:

```
docker-compose -f stack.yml up --build
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm trying the same thing!

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! This is exactly what I wanted.One more question though. I have to put the DB on a different host altogether. In that case what should I change in stack.yml ? I'm thinking of using Docker swarm similar to http://training.play-with-docker.com/swarm-service-discovery/

Comment: You can set the environment variable to the IP address of any server as described in the official docker hub repo (WORDPRESS_DB_HOST). Just spawn an instance of your database on a different host and set the correct IP address and other variables such as user, password, port, etc. in your wordpress container (don't forget to open the port on your database). But there are better solutions for this using other tools such as kubernetes or swarm as you already pointed out.